# iPhone: Programmatically store audio as ring tone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I am working on an iPhone application, where i need to store an audio file(which i get from my server) as a ringtone on the iPhone device programmatically. Is it possible to do that? What are the APIs supported for it. And, Does the Appstore allow such apps to be released?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Most probably the user will have to do it himself. You can ease-up a bit this process
for him using iTunes file sharing. See:

[How to add a ringtone from an application to ringtones of iphone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5515557/how-to-add-a-ringtone-from-an-application-to-ringtones-of-iphone)

You could also check the code of [ringtonesapp](http://code.google.com/p/ringtonesapp/).

Comment: No, i am asking can we do this from an iOS app itself, not thru desktop app.

Comment: I understand: but i think this is as close (iTunes file sharing) as you can get.

Comment: Could you also explain a bit about how the file will be shared to iTunes from my app? Automatically? (or) We have to sync my app first manually to iTunes?

Comment: For details see mbehan's answer in above SO link. 'Sync' with iTunes will be done automatically (from your code) - user will have access to your ringtones trough iTunes - therefore he will be able to set them as ringtones for his phone.

Comment: it possible contact number set ringtone  iOS

Answer (score 3):

No, you can't do this. There's no public API for this.

If you're doing this on a jailbroken device, you can just replace one of the default Apple ringtones with your ringtone.