# How can an iOS app provide a ringtone?

Tags: iphone, ios, ringtone

We have a restaurant customer who wants a ringtone with their app for users that plays burger chewing sounds for example. How can we do this?

someone told me iOS apps can't set a ringtone but I have seen a dozen ringtone apps on the App Store. What is the procedure to supply a user with a ringtone?

Answer (score 2):

You can provide the user with sounds that they can add to their ringtone library, just like dozens of apps that do this. However you are not allowed to modify the user's selected ringtone, they have to do it themselves.

Comment: What is that API called? Can't find it.

Comment: That's not an API, but it seems to be an available directory you copy your files into: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5515557/how-to-add-a-ringtone-from-an-application-to-ringtones-of-iphone