# How to set music file as call tone and message tone in iphone programmatically

Tags: ios, iphone, audio, core-audio, audiotoolbox

I have an application. In that, I have to list of music file and "Set as ringtone" option there.
I don't know how to set music file as call tone or message tone.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Set ringtone in iPhone SDK](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/829369/set-ringtone-in-iphone-sdk)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apps cannot set ringtone/message tone programmatically. That's not allowed by iOS. You might be able to save audio files so that user can access them and set them as ringtones himself.

[How to add a ringtone from an application to ringtones of iphone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5515557/how-to-add-a-ringtone-from-an-application-to-ringtones-of-iphone)

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

iOS SDK does not allow you to set the ringtone or message tone.