# Can I Stop Original ringtone and play my custom ringtone time of incoming call in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer, phone-call, ringtone

currently I am playing ringtone using AVPlayer at the time of incoming call. But in background default ringtone is playing from the system. How can I stop background ringtone of the system.

```
var player: AVPlayer?

func playSound() {
    let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "Hold Music", withExtension: "mp3")!
    
    do {
        
        let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()

        try audioSession.setActive(false, options: [])

        try audioSession.setCategory(.playback,mode: .default, options: .mixWithOthers)
        try audioSession.setActive(true)
        
        let playerItem:AVPlayerItem = AVPlayerItem(url: url)
                player = AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItem
        player?.volume = 1
        player.play()
        
    } catch let error {
        print("lool \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
}
```

Call observer for getting call status.

```
extension LandingViewController: CXCallObserverDelegate{
    
    func callObserver(_ callObserver: CXCallObserver, callChanged call: CXCall) {

        if call.hasEnded == true {
           player?.pause()
                   print("call Disconnected")

               }
               if call.isOutgoing == true && call.hasConnected == false {
                   print("call Dialing")
                   player?.pause()
               }
               if call.isOutgoing == false && call.hasConnected == false && call.hasEnded == false {
                   print("call Incoming")
                       self.playSound()
                   }
               }
               if call.hasConnected == true && call.hasEnded == false {
                   print("call Connected")
                  player?.pause()
                 
               }
      }
```

Comment: You cannot  override the native phone app ringtone.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `CallKit.CXProviderConfiguration` ringtone property to your mp3 file and make sure that the sound file includes the app you want to build in it's target membership.

The `config.ringtoneSound` property will automatically override the default ringtone.

It is used to create an instance of the configuration provider that sets the custom ringtone for the incoming call screen.

```
let config = CallKit.CXProviderConfiguration()
    config.ringtoneSound = "myRingtone.mp3"
    config.includesCallsInRecents = true
```

Using AVPlayer to play sound by detecting incoming call is not the right way.

Comment: it works for voip calls. But I am working with direct local phone call. It is not working.

Comment: I don't think so that's possible as of now - read this

https://stackoverflow.com/a/21877422/4389257